# How to post object data from react native fetch to asp.net web api

Tags: react-native, asp.net-web-api

I am new in react native I want to post a form data from react native fetch to asp.net web api.but it always receive always.
this is my react native code
**Fetch Code**

```
let response = await fetch(`${apiConfig.url}${action}`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: requestHeaders,
  body: "userName=" + encodeURIComponent(body.UserName) +
  "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(body.Password) + "&grant_type=password",
});


let responseJson = await response.json();
```

and web api code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Save(Company company)
    {
      var result = _companyRepository.Create(company);
      return Ok(result);
    }
```

but it always receive company object null.
Where is my miss take? Please point me.

Comment: get everything working in something like postman first. Once you reliably get a response from the api, then replicate the postman call in your front end app. oh and debugging is not a dead art!

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have tried first with post man it was fine. but in react native it is giving me null object.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the **[FromBody]** attribute to the parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Save([FromBody] Company company)
{
  var result = _companyRepository.Create(company);
  return Ok(result);
}
```